# Selecting the next number from a list from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have several forms on a website and when someone registers I want to allocate them a reference number. In my mind, when they click submit I could use JS to pull the next number from a list and place it into a hidden field, but then deleting that number from the list so the next form that uses it gets the next reference number.

I've tried creating arrays and using `splice()`, `delete()`, `pop()` etc, which all perform the role but obviously not on a permanent basis. Appreciate any help, I seem to just be going around in circles !

Comment: this is something that is usually better to do on the server side when you store the data from the form. Then you will be sure that you can assign the numbers. But I think that behind this question there is a wrong database structure

Comment: Yeah, if you store the number in the user's browser, it will be different for each user. You have to store it on the server somewhere (probably in a database) for it to be applicable to multiple users when they log in and use the forms.

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate them the number only after saving the data. In that case you can use the ID of the stored element in the database (LAST_INSERT_ID() for MySQL, if you have an autoincrement column). There's no point in allocating identifiers before because the user might not even complete filling the form.

One other solution could be to generate a number based on an algorithm. You can for example use a simple solution of getting the javascript Date as it's a number containing the number of milliseconds, and the chances of collisions are pretty slim (because that number would have to be generated in the same millisecond). Over this you can also use a hashing or crc function but in that case you'd have to double check that this identifier is not already generated for somebody else.

Still, I think the ID after saving is the best solution as the database guarantees you a different and unique number.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, this was going to be my solution, however I use a third party CRM system so I don't have access to that level of code. The JS date is a good idea though, would always be individual.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
// Array of dummy reference numbers
var referenceNumberArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// shift() method to remove the first element from an array.
var assignedReferenceNumber = referenceNumberArr.shift();
 
/**
 * updateReferenceArr() method to filter out the assigned reference number from an array.
 *
 * @param {object} initalArray - sort option parameters.
 * @param {number} assignedNumber - assigned reference number.
 * @returns {object} returns filtered reference number array.
 */
function updateReferenceArr(initalArray, assignedNumber) {
 return initalArray.filter(item => item !== assignedNumber)
}

var referenceNumberArr = updateReferenceArr(referenceNumberArr, assignedReferenceNumber);

// Filtered array.
console.log(referenceNumberArr);
```